# Is it possible to check whether the first div ,among a set of div having same class,have the display block attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I need to check whether the first div, among a set of div having same class, have the `display:block` attribute? How can I accomplish this with jQuery?

html code is like:

```
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock bb-vertical" >     

    <div class="bb-item" style="display: block;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
</div>
```

Here the 6 div in 'bb-bookblock' div having class name ="bb-item".  I need to know how can I check whether currently which child div having the attribute display:block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the display by using `.css('display')`:

To get the first item, you can either use `.eq(0)` or a `.first()` or a first child selector

```js
console.log($('#bb-bookblock').children('.bb-item').eq(0).css('display'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock bb-vertical" >     
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: block;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery API Links**

[More info on .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[More info on .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

[More info on .first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score 1):

> which child div having the attribute `display:block`.

You can use `index()` to get the index of the visible div and `:visible` can filter the displayed div. See the example below:

```js
var whichDiv = $('.bb-bookblock .bb-item:visible').index();

console.log('div', whichDiv, 'is visible.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock bb-vertical">
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: block;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:first` selector to get the first matching `div` and then check the `display` property set on it, something like this:

```
var firstIsBlock = $('.bb-bookblock .bb-item:first').css('display') == 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```js
if($('.bb-bookblock .bb-item:first-child').css('display')=='block'){
  alert('its blocked..');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock bb-vertical" >     
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: block;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use first child selector to select the first item in list`if($('.bb-bookblock .bb-item:first-child').css('display')=='block')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using for each loop inside .bb-bookblock div, it may help you.

```
var a=$('.bb-bookblock').children();
    $.each(a,function(k,v){
    var disp=$(v).css('display')
    if(disp==='block')
    {
    console.log(v);
    }
    })
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/r969r3Lg/)